# How to deploy and access portlet using IBM portal server

Tags: portal, websphere-portal

I have a Portlet that I know works and deployed successfully about 3 years ago. Now someone has asked for a change and I've totally forgotten how to deploy it for development on my local machine.

I have a local copy of IBM Portal server and have exported the portlet as a war file and deployed inside IBM Portal Server like so.

```
Go to http://mymachine:10038/wps/portal/. Under Portal Management
Select portlets.
```

[image]

```
I then selected Web Modules and installed my way file successfully.
Now it appears under the Portlets tab...
```

[image]

So far so good. But I am stuck now on how to hit my Portal application in the browser. How do I actually get to the Portlet url?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Build portlet as .war file

2) In portal Administration go to Web Modules

3) Lookup installed portlet and press Update or Instal button if new
   portlet application

4) Go to Manage Pages and create empty page or select existing page

5) Press pen button to select and put portlet on the page

6) Open the page and you should see your portlet

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this tomorrow. When you say open the page. How exactly do I do that? Can I do is via the portal admin console? If not how do I know what the url is?

Comment: You should see new page in top menu after page being created.

Comment: Thanks so much. I tried this and it worked this morning.